# Visualizing shared instances of p-values<alpha across large numbers of treatments

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-visualization, data-mining, correspondence-analysis, biplot

Assume a data table that presents the p-values of a large number of independent runs of a statistical hypothesis test. Each run represents a single test with two possible hypotheses (i.e., null and alternative) on a particular dataset (or treatment or whatever you want to call it). A total of *d* different datasets (represented in the table as rows) and *h* different hypotheses (represented as columns) were evaluated to generate the table. The data table, thus, portrays the p-values of *d x h* different runs.

```
     |   h1    h2    h3    h4
----------------------------
d001 | 0.02* 0.33  0.01* 0.46
d002 | 0.14  0.25  0.03* 0.11
d003 | 0.01* 0.68  0.01* 0.04*
...
d998 | 0.02* 0.71  0.01* 0.13
d999 | 0.03* 0.29  0.02* 0.33
```

Since the number of datasets evaluated ranges in the hundreds, I would like to find a way to visualize shared instances of significance graphically. Specifically, I would like to highlight if any of the hypotheses (i.e., columns) share instances of p-values<alpha with other such hypotheses for the same datasets (i.e., rows). In the above example, hypotheses *h1* and *h3* share instances of p-values<alpha across numerous datasets.

What general type of visualization would you recommend? (I'll set up the R code myself and am just interested in the type of visualization that you would recommend.)

Comment: As a preliminary step, did you correct for multiple hypotheses? A raw p-value of 0.05 is not nearly significant when conducting thousands of hypothesis tests.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Yes, a Bonferroni correction of the p-values is in place.

Answer (score 1):

**Ultimately, you want a [biplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biplot).**  Briefly, a biplot rerepresents your units / rows as points in a 2-dimensional space that maximizes the amount of the original variability that can be captured.  (These are the first two principal components; for more, see: [Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691).)  It likewise rerepresents your variables / columns as the tips of arrows in the same space on the scatterplot.  In general, the closer two points are, the more similar they are; the closer the tips of two arrows are, the more similar the variables are; and the closer a point is to a variable, the larger the proportion of its mass is associated with the variable, and vice-versa.  Be aware that a high-dimensional space is being collapsed into 2-dimensions, so there will be some error there, but that's the gist of it.  There is a lot of good information about [biplot](/questions/tagged/biplot)s available on the site, click the tag, sort by votes and start reading from the top to learn more.

I strongly believe it is best to use the full information in data and not dichotomize (e.g., into significant vs. non-significant).  Here is a biplot of your example dataset of p-values, coded in R:

```r
d = read.table(text="dataset    h1    h2    h3    h4
                        d001  0.02  0.33  0.01  0.46
                     ...
                        d999  0.03  0.29  0.02  0.33", header=T)
rownames(d) = d$dataset
d           = d[,-1]
d
#        h1   h2   h3   h4
# d001 0.02 0.33 0.01 0.46
# d002 0.14 0.25 0.03 0.11
# d003 0.01 0.68 0.01 0.04
# d998 0.02 0.71 0.01 0.13
# d999 0.03 0.29 0.02 0.33

windows()
  biplot(prcomp(d, scale=T))
```

We can see that `h1` is similar to `h3`, `d003` is similar to `d998` in pattern, and that `d998` has most of its mass in `h2`.

[image: PCA biplot]

If you really want to know only about significance, you can conduct a [correspondence analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis).  That also outputs a biplot, although by convention usually with points for both rows and columns, and the table is decomposed using a different metric than correlations (which PCA uses).  We also have several good threads on [correspondence-analysis](/questions/tagged/correspondence-analysis).

```r
d2           = as.data.frame(sapply(d, function(j){  as.numeric(j<.05)  }))
rownames(d2) = rownames(d)
#      h1 h2 h3 h4
# d001  1  0  1  0
# d002  0  0  1  0
# d003  1  0  1  1
# d998  1  0  1  0
# d999  1  0  1  0
library(ca)
windows()
  plot(ca(d))
```

We get generally similar information here.

[image: Correspondence analysis biplot]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to draft such a detailed answer! I will read up on biplots and correspondence analysis given your links. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, @MichaelG.